# is it ok to use div inside tbody if not how to slidetoggle tbody

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, slidetoggle

I need to slideDown table rows. Because of sliding is not ok for table I wanted to wrap this rows inside tbody and than div so I could slide down them with div. **Is it allowed to use div inside tbody? **

If not, how can I do this?

And yet, is there anything indexing tbody like n-th(or odd/even selectors) in th, td?

Any Suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just use the `<tbody>` without the `<div>`? If you need a container for a specific rows *that's what a `<tbody>` is for*.

Comment: As I tried, slideToggle doesn't work properly with any element of table